# Inserting double into SQL Server 2012 Decimal column leads to imprecision

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2012, double, decimal

Having a lot of trouble getting a program to insert the actual number without any imprecision from C# to SQL server.

For example, here is the code for how the data is handled in C# before pushing to the SQL Server:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(double));

dt.Rows.Add(6.5);
dt.Rows.Add(7);
dt.Rows.Add(8);

SqlConnection con;
string sqlCmd;
SqlCommand cmd;

using (con = new SqlConnection(Common.DBLink))
{
                con.Open();
                SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con);
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "NumberTable";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                con.Close();
}
```

But if I have a number like 2.85 in there, it gets inserted as 2.8499.  The SQL column is a `DECIMAL(10,4)` datatype.  This only happens for very few numbers.  It never happens for values like 12.5 or 20.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Note for the future. "double" and "decimal" are not spelled the same. Chances are they're different things. You will find this applies to many more pairs of "things" in your life: if they were the same thing, they'd likely be spelled the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a `decimal` value, don't store it as a `double` in your `DataTable`.

Change your column type to a `decimal` and try it again:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Number", typeof(decimal));
```

You can find a lot of helpful information by searching for *"c# double vs decimal"*, such as [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when), or Jon Skeet's articles on [Decimals](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/decimal.aspx) and [Doubles](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/FloatingPoint.aspx).

Comment: We did try this and it didn't work.  Still thinking of other ideas.